# Jenkins: How to execute shell script in a Windows slave

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a Windows slave, with bash installed. I'm trying to run a shell script on it as a pre-build step. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run bash with the script as an argument:

```
bash yourscript <arguments to your script here>
```

You may also need to supply the complete path to bash depending on your environment.

Comment: You must also make sure that the jenkins service is started as the correct user. The standard NT Authority user will not be able to run a bash shell.

Answer (score 2):

If your bash on Windows is part of a Cygwin install, the [cygpath plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cygpath+Plugin) will allow you to use 'Execute Shell' and do #!/bin/bash at the top of it, just like you would do for unix slaves.