# How to run shell script using Jenkins on windows setup

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins setup on windows machine,I also have shell script which i want to run using Jenkins. How to run this script any idea.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745524/jenkins-how-to-execute-shell-script-in-a-windows-slave ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on windows
2. Make use of the
   [Cygpath plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cygpath+Plugin) for Jenkins

Comment: Cygpath plugin conflicts with SonarQube analysis and fails the build. I have just installed the plugin but not defined any configuration in jenkins job and configure system of jenkins even then it was taking wrong cygwin path and executing sonarqube with it.

Comment: With the Cygwin + Cygpath setup , all file paths will change to unix style paths .